# Traversal algorithm for an optimal item collecting route in the game "Eternal Return: Black Survival"

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, traveling-salesman

I am currently trying to implement a algorithm for the game "Eternal Return: Black Survival" as a kind of exercise in Rust.
Since the game may not be familiar to many, here is a quick explenation so you can understand what I want to achieve.

Eternal Return is a Multiplayer Online Battle Arena (or **MOBA**) with battle royale like win conditions. The game consists of 16 Players all starting in diffrent locations on the map that is divided into "Zones". You can select your rough **starting location** by selecting a **Zone** you want to spawn in. After that you will spawn in a random location there.

[image: The map, divided into diffrent zones.]

Now each zone has a diffrent pre-defined set of items that can be found there. For example in **Archery Range** you can find: [5 Bamboo, 6 Iron Ball, 5 Bow ...]. The items are found in crates (the crates have a static location between games) and are spread pseudo randomly across them.

You need items to **combine** or **craft** them into **more complex items** that **can not be found in crates** and give you adventagous stats for fighting the other players which is the reason you want them.

[image: A example]

Now a common practice is to have a pre-defined build of items you want in the end and to then design a **route** that after traversed, gives you all the **crate items** you need to craft your **pre-defined build**. Since retriving all your items **as quickly as possible and as efficiently as possible**, I want to crate an algorithm that, given a build (or all sub **crate items** you need since it's pretty easy to just infer them from the **final items** you want), generates an optimal, time efficient route through the zones.

Additionally there are so called "Hyperloops" in zome zones that can teleport you to another Zone (to a random location there).

I thought this kind of could resemble a graph theory problem but:

1. Im unsure how to represent the problem in a model correctly
2. How I would then solve it

If you only model by Zones and not by loot crates, a big problem is that you somehow need to take into account how much time you need in each zone which is dependend on luck, the zone itself and how many and what kind of items you need.

Also time-taken depends hughely on what route you take through the zone to get to the other zone, which is why I thought about not modeling the zones as nodes but the **edges between the zones** as nodes, measuring the time it takes from one node to another as a kind of cost. Doing this, you could **brute force** all routes through zones that give you your desired items to then find the fastest of the routes by sorting them by **eta to complete**.

Then you could think of **each crate** as a **node** and then plan a route through that but the spawn location randomness and the ranomness of which item is in a specific crate would really make this hard. A interesting idea in this direction I thought of would be running a kind of **Monte-Carlo Simulation** (perhaps even some kind of **MCTS**) to find a good, but not "mathematically prooven optimal route".

Do you have any ideas for a good model for this problem and maybe even a good solution for this problem? Am I completly wrong for thinking of this as a graph theory problem? How could graph theory maybe help here?

Comment: You said there is randomness in this game. How is it formally defined? Which things does it affect? Do note though, that you will need an **active** agent (it will recalculate the best path each time it needs to) if there is randomness in the items \ possible routes that the player gets.

Comment: It affects: what item you find in what crate and where in a zone you spawn

Comment: The goal is not to make a in-game app that helps you (since that would be cheating) put helps you to plan a pre defined route.

Comment: Then you cannot guarantee that taking that same route will always be optimal. Say, fpr example, you got nothing in the first zone while walking through the route you chose. And in all other zones, there isn't the specific material you need from the first zone. So, you would prefer to stay in the first zonr and disregard the route you chose.

Comment: I know I cannot guarantee that taking the same route will be optimal but since item spread is pseudo random e.g. in each Zone a fixed number of items occur but it is random where they are the problem does converge.

Comment: (*`zome zones`* or *some zones*?)